# Why doesn't a constructor accept parameters of a class with lower accessibility?

Tags: c#, constructor

Here it is:

I have two Forms and one Class, I want to pass the instance of this Class from
Form1 to Form2 through a parameter (which belongs to the second form's constructor).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Class1 cl = new Class1();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm_2 = new Form2(cl);
    }
}
```

Thus, I receive the folowing error:

*Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Class1' is less accessible than method 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form2.Form2(WindowsFormsApplication1.Class1)'*

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(Class1 c)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Class1 c_1 = new Class1();
        c_1 = c;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where is Class1 defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined your `Class1` as `internal`:

```
internal class Class1
{
}
```

Or (the same):

```
class Class1
{
}
```

But you have a `public` method (in this case a constructor) that accepts a parameter of type `Class1`. `public` means that it is visible from any other assembly, but `internal` means that it is only visible from the assembly that defines it (your assembly). So, you have a method that anyone can call, which accepts a parameter of a type that only you can see. That's not going to work. You have two options here:

#### Option 1: Make `Class1` public

```
public class Class1
{ }
```

If you don't mind the class being accessible from any assembly ever.

#### Option 2: Make the constructor of your form internal

```
internal Form2(Class1 c)
{ }
```

If you don't mind that the form can never be created by any other assembly except yours.

Comment: Upvoted because of the careful explanation of the two options. Most of the time one should choose restricted accessibility if possible, so I recommend "Option 2" unless `Form2` really needs to be instantiated from the outside. Some of the other answers mention only "Option 1", and that's kind of incomplete.

Answer (score 8):

`Class1` is an internal class of your assembly, but you are making a public method of a public class that takes `Class1` as a parameter. It's like you're publically posting an ad saying "we're accepting applications for a job, but you can only get a copy of the application form if you work here already". It doesn't make any sense, so the compiler is disallowing it.

Answer (score 1):

Class1 needs to be declared as a public class i.e. `public class Class1() {...}` in order  be used by other public classes

Comment: @SLaks I think used is the correct term here. "in order to be exposed by other public classes" isn't correct if we are talking about classes outside of Form1.

Comment: Visible to other classes could also work.  I think Eric's analogy makes it the most clear.

Comment: @Justin: `Form1` can _use_ an internal class, as long as the type is not exposed by a public member.

Answer (score 0):

Your Class1 should be public as the Form2 and its constructor has public scope. If we do not make the Class1 as public, then the access is limited. That is why the compiler displays this message.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form2(Class1 c)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Class1 c_1 = new Class1();
        c_1 = c;
    }
}

public class Class1
{

    // Your code for Class1
}
```