# Can't close a form from other form

Tags: c#, forms, hide

Maybe this is a really dumb problem, but I can't close a form.

This is what I'm trying to do:
Start Main form -> Open second form -> Open third form and close the second form..

I use this code to open the second form:

```
this.Hide();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
pauzescreen p = new pauzescreen();
p.Show();
```

And I use this code to open the third form:

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.TopMost = true;
form1.Show();
form1.Activate();
```

And then I close the second form with this code: (Here is the problem, this doesn't work..)

```
pauzescreen pauze = new pauzescreen();
pauze.Hide();
```

Can't explain it very well, but what it does it creates an fullscreen screen capture at the second form (Pauzeform) and at the third form you can select an region.

The second form and third form have no border and are maximized.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating two separate references to two separate forms: `p` and `pauze`. To close the original form you would need to retain the reference and call `Close()` or `Hide()` on that:

```
pauzescreen p = new pauzescreen();
p.Show();

// other stuff

p.Hide();
```

Comment: Think about buying a car. You choose to buy a particular model of a car. You can't buy the _concept_ of the model, you have to buy an example of the model (e.g. the one in blue that is in the showroom). If you buy that blue car, then anything you do to it only happens to that blue car, and not to the other cars left in the showroom. Your form `pauzescreen` is like the model of the car, and `p` and `pauze` are like the showroom examples of the car. In order to close `p`, you must call close on it, not on a new version of it (`pauze`).

Comment: Hmmm...that doesn't make as much sense as it did when I typed it.

Comment: I understand it, but I'm closing the form from an other form then where I started it. I also tried to hide it from the main form, that also didn't work.

Comment: I would perhaps take another look at the dependencies you have between forms. Ideally it would only go in one direction, e.g. a form has knowledge of the form it opens, but that second form does not have knowledge of the first. In order for the second form to have an impact on a form about which it should not have knowledge, you might need to create some event handlers to pass back information to the first form so that it can act.

Answer (score 0):

As Sid pointed out, the main problem is that you're creating a new instance of your second form when writing

```
pauzescreen p = new pauzescreen();
```

As you're trying to close it in a part of the code different from where your form's instantiation is, one fittable solution, instead of handling events, is to keep reference of your object by passing it as a parameter to the class or method attempting the closure.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256208/why-doesnt-a-constructor-accept-parameters-of-a-class-with-lower-accessibility) is an example of how you could work with the same object in two different classes.

Answer (score 0):

I have a multiform application, and I'm quite fond of using the Program class.

```
static class Program
{
    // declare the forms in the program member space
    static Form1 firstForm;
    static Form2 secondForm;
    static Form3 thirdForm;
}
```

What I do is in the Main method, initialize the forms.

```
static void Main()
{
    firstForm = new Form1()
    // ... so on and so forth
}
```

Then, whenever you want to show or hide those forms, use

```
// To hide a form, use its Hide method
Program.firstForm.Hide()

// To show a form, use its Show method
Program.secondForm.Show()
```

in your code. It's worked in my applications just fine like that. :)